# Without rollback function,is there any meaning on using UserTransaction on Java?

Tags: java

I am using `javax.transaction.UserTransaction` for maintaining transaction in my java code.But In our code found there is a call for `begin()` and `commit()` and no call for `rollback()`.

So, Is there any meaning when using like this?

Please guide me to get out of this confusion?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html#rollback()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sample of your code would be of great help.

Anyway, generally speaking, there's no need for your code to contain calls to both `commit()` and `rollback()` in order to make sense. You simply may not need to handle yourself rollback cases.

If the thread crashes for any reason somewhere between the call to `begin()` and the call to `commit()` (that is, in mid-transaction), the transaction will be rolled back and the operations executed so far inside the transaction are not applied to the transaction-enabled module.

Answer (score 1):

You can see there is a `rollback()`

```
   UserTransaction userTransaction=new UserTransaction() {
       @Override
       public int getStatus() throws SystemException {
           return 0;  
       }

       @Override
       public void begin() throws NotSupportedException, SystemException {

       }

       @Override
       public void commit() throws RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, SystemException {

       }

       @Override
       public void rollback() throws IllegalStateException, SecurityException, SystemException {

       }

       @Override
       public void setRollbackOnly() throws IllegalStateException, SystemException {

       }

       @Override
       public void setTransactionTimeout(int i) throws SystemException {

       }
   } ;
```

When ever `RuntimeException` throws you can `rollback()` as required.

Comment: :Yes I know... I mean in our module there is no call to rollback(). That's why i asked is it useful?

Comment: @Saravanan what do you mean by your module?